# Generating a number between 1 and 2 java Math.random() with a probability set for each number

Tags: java, math, random, probability

I'm trying to generate a `random numbers` between 1 and 2 using the imported `math.random()` class and set the `probability` for each number.

The code below set the `probability` to be 1/2 for the two number each 1/2

```
int randomInt = (Math.random() <= 0.5) ? 1 : 2;
```

I want to be able to set the `probability` for each individual numbers, for example number 1 (20% probability) and number 2 (80% probability) or the ratio of 20:80. any solution?

Edit : The program I need to make is able to set the `probability` for number 1 and number 2 separately. like asking the `user` to input the `probability` for number 1 and 2

Comment: Where exactly are you stuck? It seems like you understood the logic, and just need to replace 0.5 with a different fraction.

Comment: Does `rand() <= 0.2 ? 1 : 2` work?

Comment: i mean is there  a way to control both probability maybe, int randomInt = (Math.random() <= 0.5(for 1) + 0,5(for 2)) ? 1 : 2; because the programme i need to make is be able to set the probability for num 1 and num 2 seperately. like asking the user to input the probability for num 1 and 2

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do in many ways.

Option 1: Simplest

```java
int randomInt = (Math.random() <= 0.2) ? 1 : 2;
```

Option 2: Slightly intresting

```java
// 20:80
final int seedList[] =  {
        1, //20%
        2,2,2,2//80%
};
for (int i =0; i < 10; i++) {
        int position = (int) (Math.random() * seedList.length);
        System.out.println(seedList[position]);
}
```

Any many more ways. I think you can be creative about solving this.

Comment: the programme i need to make is be able to set the probability for number 1 and number 2 separately. like asking the user to input the probability for number 1 and 2

Answer (score 0):

This method will take an arbitrary number of numbers to be used as weighting the result. There is no check in the code but for correctness the sum of them should be 100.

```
public static int randomInt(int... ratios) {
    int randomInt = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(1, 101);
    int previous = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < ratios.length; i++) {
        if (randomInt < (ratios[i] + previous)) {
            return i + 1;
        }
        previous += ratios[i];
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Example, the following call would give 1 10%, 2 40%, 3 20% and 4 30% probability.

```
randomInt(10, 40, 20, 30)
```

Comment: can't find symbol ratios. do i need to make a new class?

Comment: No it’s a static method. ratios is the parameter

Answer (score 0):

Since your selection set contains only two items (1,2) you can infer the probability of 1 when the user enters the probability of 2.

```
public class OneOrTwo {
  public double probability1 = 0.2;
  public int next() {
    return (Math.random() <= probability1 ? 1 : 2);
  }
  public void setProbabilityOne(double p1) {
    probability1 = p1;
  }
  public void setProbabilityTwo(double p2) {
    probability1 = 1.0 - p2;
  }
  ... driver method, get user input, all that stuff ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is make it possible to parametrize the "0.5" in your code. For example, use a variable for it:

```
static int randomOneOrTwo(double probabilityOfOne) {
    return (Math.random() < probabilityOfOne) ? 1 : 2;
}
```

Now `randomOneOrTwo(0.20)` will return 1 with 20% probability, 2 with 80% probability.